# Re-shaping the Data Result to Different Custom Models On The Fly

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

Let's assume that I have a table named Gift with a few fields.

```
Gift{
  Field1,
  Field2,
  Field3
}
```

I have a WEB API function, by which user/admin can retrieve records of Gift. However, I want to prevent  Field3 from being exposed to users, which means that only administrators can view all the 3 fields.

Below are my model class definitions:

```
public class OM_Gift_FE
{
    public string Field1 { set; get; }
    public string Field2 { set; get; }

    public static implicit operator OM_Gift_FE(OM_Gift_BO gift_bo){
        return new OM_Gift_FE
        {
            Field1 = gift_bo.Field1,
            Field2 = gift_bo.Field2
        };
    }
}

public class OM_Gift_BO
{
    public string Field1 { set; get; }
    public string Field2 { set; get; }
    public string Field3 { set; get; }
}
```

And in one of my API method:

```
    List<OM_Gift_EF> bidGifts;

    if (userLevel > 2)  // admin user at back office
    {
        bidGifts = objEntity.ExecuteStoreQuery<OM_Gift_BO>("SELECT * FROM gift").ToList();
    }
    else    // user at front end
    {
        bidGifts = objEntity.ExecuteStoreQuery<OM_Gift_FE>("SELECT * FROM gift").ToList();
    }
    // continue to process bidGifts
```

Of course it fails, and the easiest workaround seems to be introducing another variable of List, and repeating the following code in both if and else blocks. But I am curious whether I can handle this concisely with just one variable?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The operator you have defined casts OM_Gift_BO to OM_Gift_FE. In your code you are trying to assign a List<OM_Gift_FE> to a List<OM_Gift_BO>, which is the other way around.

Comment: Implicit type conversion would have failed anyway of course, since the operator is defined on a OM_Gift_FE object, not a List<OM_Gift_FE>

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, thank you so much. So there is no way to let .NET FW handle it automatically?